# Replacing Column headings

Tags: python, replace, multiple-columns

I want to replace multi-columns heading with specific words.
I know I can create a dictionary for T1_A to A, T1_B to B and so on

However, is there any method like find and replace? What if my columns are up to T1_Z.....
Thanks

For example,

```
T1_A  T1_B  T1_C  ---> *A  *B  *C
   1     2     3        1   2   3
   1     2     4        1   2   4
```

Comment: Have you seen the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function?

Comment: yes. But how can i write in a faster away apart from using df.rename(columns={"T1_A": "*A", "T1_B": "B"}). 
Can I have sth like all 'T1' replace by '*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename also accepts a function. Try this:

```py
df = df.rename(columns= lambda c : "*" + c[-1])
```

Or you could do this:

```py
df = df.rename(columns= lambda c : c.replace('T1_', '*'))
```

Comment: Or, similarly, `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("T1_", "*")`. I personally like the idea of using `rename()` the best though.